# Is there some class that implements logging facility, that I can use?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to use logger in my application. 
I looking for some class in .net framework that i can use for this purpose - and i did not found.

Is there some ready library in .net framework that i can use for organize simple log ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you were looking in the framework, did you not see or not like the System.Diagnostics.Trace [1] framework?

As already mentioned log4net [2]  is a good framework, we use it extensively. You may also be interested in the Log facility in the Castle Windsor IoC framework [3].

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx

[2] http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

[3] http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/logging/index.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many third-party libraries for this. Check out [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) for instance.

But if all you want is to write some lines to a file it may be enough to create a text file that you write to. In that case you can use `System.IO.File.CreateText(filename)` to get a `StreamWriter` that you can log to. Then use `StreamWriter.WriteLine` to write to the log. Finally you should Close the `StreamWriter` when you are done logging.

Answer (score 2):

Add a [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) to your app.config and use System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine to write to the log.

You can have separate listeners for writing to a text file, event log etc.

Answer (score 1):

[elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is good option, please check

and log4net is another
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Log4Net_Configuration.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) are the most popular ones. I have mostly worked with NLog and are pretty satisfied with it. These logging frameworks allow you to define different rules and targets for logging, changing these on runtime (for debugging an app in production environment, for example) as well as using reflection so that your log messages can include things like the name of the class the log is originating from.